# How Retain cycles occurs in Memory Management?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

Can some explain the retain cycles problem with a sample program?

Comment: Similar question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791322/retain-cycles-why-is-that-such-a-bad-thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791322/retain-cycles-why-is-that-such-a-bad-thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *b = [NSMutableArray array];
[a addObject:b];
[b addObject:a];
```

When `b` is inserted into `a`, `b` is retained, likewise `a` when its inserted into `b`. As both now have a *strong reference* to each other, neither will get deallocated unless you manually break the cycle by e.g. removing one from the other.

Note that the Cocoa Memory Management guide also contains [a section on retain cycles](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1000810) and includes an explanation of *weak references*, which help with these problems.

Comment: Hi Georg Fritzche,

Thanks for the wonderful example. I read the Weak references you have referred. And how do you implement weak reference in case of the example you have provided above?

Comment: @Krishnan: You can use a different container that doesn't use strong references. For `CFMutableArray` (which is toll-free bridged to `NSMutableArray`) you could set the `retain` and `release` functions to `NULL` - see [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CFArrayCallBacks). That way you get a weak referencing array.

Answer (score 1):

I've got just the right article(s) for you:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/06/assign-retain-copy-pitfalls-in-obj-c.html

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-management-tutorial-video/