# Objective-C – Sending data from NSObject subclass to an UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have an `UIViewController` which has a `UITableView` inside. In this view controller I want to display some data that I have downloaded from the internet. So for this I have created a helper class called `OfficesParser` which is supposed to do the following:

1. Download the data from the internet with `ASIHTTPRequest`
2. Process the data with a JSON parser
3. When finished, send the data back to my view controller

In my view controller I'm `alloc`ing and `init`ing my helper class in `-viewDidLoad` like so:

```
self.officesParser = [[[OfficesParser alloc] init] autorelease]; //officesParser is a retained property
```

Then in `-viewWillAppear:` I call the the method for the officesParser object that will start the download process like so:

```
[self.officesParser download];
```

In my helper class `OfficesParser` `ASIHTTPRequest` has a delegate method that tells you when a queue has finished downloading. So from this method I want send the data to my view controller. I would think this would work, but it didn't:

```
- (void)queueFinished:(ASINetworkQueue *)queue {

    NSArray *offices = [self offices];
    OfficesViewController *ovc = [[OfficesViewController alloc] init];
    [ovc setOffices:offices];

}
```

With this code in mind, how would you achieve what I'm trying to do with proper code?

Answer (score 3):

You need to take a look at [delegates and protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html). They're exactly what you're looking for, as they let classes communicate without having to persist a reference. [Here](http://banagale.com/ios-objective-c-app-delegates-explained-using-birds.htm) is another explanation on them.

Comment: To avoid retain cycle use delegation, that is the easy way to do this.

Comment: It's not a hack. It's an architecture pattern designed to do exactly what you're trying to do. References aren't always the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
OfficesViewController *ovc = [[OfficesViewController alloc] init];
```

Creates new instance property of `OfficesViewController`. Since it's a new instance it does not have a connection to the `OfficesViewController` you triggered after downloading and parsing process. To be able to comunicate b/w `OfficesViewController` and `OfficesParser` create a modified init method for `OfficesParser` that allows week pointer to the `OfficesViewController`.

```
@interface OfficesParser ()

@property(nonatomic,assign)OfficesViewController *ovc;

@end

@implementation OfficesParser

@synthesize ovc;

-(id)initWithDelegate:(OfficesViewController*)delegate{
    ovc = delegate;
    return [self init];
}
```

Now you can access your ovc delegate.

```
- (void)queueFinished:(ASINetworkQueue *)queue {
    NSArray *offices = [self offices];
    [ovc setOffices:offices];
}
```

Finally create your OfficesParser like that

```
self.officesParser = [[OfficesParser alloc] initWithDelegate: self];
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this! Shouldnt the property be declared with retain and in the code are you actually using the PVC property? (at least I can't see a property call)

Comment: It's declared as assign as it is week reference. and `ovc` is used in `queueFinished` method `[ovc setOffices:offices];`

Comment: I use weak reference to avoid retain cycles. To find out more aobut retain cycles read this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791322/retain-cycles-why-is-that-such-a-bad-thing/791372#791372](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791322/retain-cycles-why-is-that-such-a-bad-thing/791372#791372)