# Using CCSpriteBatchNode to animate multiple objects

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

I want to use CCSpriteBatchNode to animate "enemies" in my game.
I've read in a tutorial by Ray Wenderlich [awesome guy] which can be found here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d
that in order to use CCSpriteBatchNode and gain from using it I should add sprites used in the animation as children of the sprite batch node.

What I intended to do is to have a CCNode and add the sprite used for animation as child of this node. I wanted to do it this way because apart from the animation I also have things like health bars etc which follow the animation around the scene. If I have everything under the same CCNode I can easily manipulate it.

From what I understand I will have to add the sprite used for animation as child of the sprite batch node, hold reference to it in my enemy object and change it's position and other parameters along with changing position of the node which will contain health bars etc.

Is this correct?
Is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add CCSprite objects to a CCSpriteBatchNode. And you can't add a node twice to the node hierarchy. So you're correct that you'll need to have a reference to your sprite-batched sprite. Essentially you'll be implementing the View-Controller pattern, the sprite being the "view" and the controller is the object that updates (controls) the sprite properties like position.

Be careful not to retain the sprite however, because this can easily cause a [retain cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791322/retain-cycles-why-is-that-such-a-bad-thing).